# read directory files function

Tags: php, function, dir

i have 10 main folders that contains some sub-folders. i want to create a loop which go over the main folder (each one of the 10) and create  tag for each one.

i'm a beginner in php, and i manage to create a program which read the directory, and creates the links. BUT.... the code is the same code in each directory, and i dont want to replicate the same file 10 times, so if i would like to change something it will be a headache...
i cant manage to create the proper function for this.

can somone please help me?

```
<?php   

$dir = ".";
$handle = opendir($dir);
$entry = readdir($handle);
$foldername=basename(getcwd());

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            if (is_dir($entry) === true){        
                $foldername=basename($entry);                                           
               echo "<a class='directory' href='http://the_link/".$entry."'> ".$foldername." </a>";
            }                   
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}           
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Usage example :

```
$ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../");
foreach ($ite as $file) {
  echo $file . "\n";   
}
```

In your case, you can use :

```
$dir = ".";
$ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
foreach ($ite as $entry) {
  if (is_dir($entry)) {
    $foldername = basename($entry);
    echo "<a class='directory' href='http://the_link/".$entry."'> ".$foldername." </a>";
}
```

Or in a function :

```
function displayDir($dir) {
  $ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
  foreach ($ite as $entry) {
    if (is_dir($entry)) {
      $foldername = basename($entry);
      echo "<a class='directory' href='http://the_link/".$entry."'> ".$foldername." </a>";
  }
}
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) for more details.

Comment: +1 for using RecursiveDirectoryIterator: [Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: this code isnt valid, as each loop element only has private methods

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?php

  getDirectoryList("your directory path");

  function getDirectoryList ($directory) 
  {
    $results = array();   
    $handler = opendir($directory);

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {    
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $results[] = $file;
      }
    }
    closedir($handler);

    return $results;

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For scan folder and sub folder:

```
function scan_folder($from_folder = '/your/default/path/') {  

        if ($handle = @opendir ( $from_folder )) {

                while ( $file = readdir ( $handle ) ) {
                        if (is_file ( $from_folder . $file )) {      

                            echo $from_folder . $file;

                        } else if ((is_dir ( $from_folder . $file )) && ($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
                                 echo $from_folder . $file;
                        }
                }

                closedir ( $handle );
        }

}
```

Use:

```
scan_folder('/your/path/to/scan/');
```

Function used:

- [opendir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)
- [readdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)
- [is_dir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)
- [is_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)